# Split date range into months (Using CTE)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this query and I want an alternative for this query without using recursive CTE.
Can Anybody please edit and update the query

```
DECLARE @d TABLE(value int ,from_date DATE, to_date DATE);
INSERT @d VALUES (7,'2013-11-05','2013-11-25'),(8,'2013-07-05','2013-12-25'),(7,'2013-02-07','2013-04-14');
WITH cte AS
(SELECT value,from_date
      , to_date
      , from_date AS mo_from_date
      , DATEADD(day, day(from_date)* -1 + 1, from_date) AS bom_date
   FROM @d
UNION ALL
SELECT value, from_date
     , to_date
     , DATEADD(month,1,bom_date)
     , DATEADD(month,1,bom_date)
  FROM cte
 where DATEADD(month,1,mo_from_date) < to_date
)
SELECT value,mo_from_date
     , CASE when to_date < DATEADD(month,1,bom_date) THEN
           to_date
       ELSE
           DATEADD(day, -1, DATEADD(month,1,bom_date))
       END AS mo_to_date
  FROM cte
```

output:

```
value   mo_from_date    mo_to_date
7   2013-11-05  2013-11-25
8   2013-07-05  2013-07-31
8   2013-08-01  2013-08-31
8   2013-09-01  2013-09-30
8   2013-10-01  2013-10-31
8   2013-11-01  2013-11-30
8   2013-12-01  2013-12-25
9   2013-02-07  2013-02-28
10  2013-03-01  2013-03-31
11  2013-04-01  2013-04-14
```

I have tried below query but its not working,can anybody update this query

```sql
;with MonthList as (
    select 
        DATEADD(month, M, '12/1/1899') as 'FirstDay',
        dateadd(day, -1, dateadd(month, M + 1, '12/1/1899')) as 'LastDay',
        DATEADD(month, M + 1, '12/1/1899') as 'FirstDayNextMonth'
    from (
        select top 3000 ROW_NUMBER() over (order by s.name) as 'M'
        from master..spt_values s) s
)

select
   t.value, ml.FirstDay as from_date, ml.LastDay as to_date
from
    @d t
    inner join MonthList ml
        on  t.from_date < ml.FirstDayNextMonth
            and t.to_date >= ml.FirstDay
```

Comment: Use a tally or Calendar Table.

Comment: Please suugest how

Comment: That *is* my suggestion. Use a tally use a Calendar Table...

Comment: Not getting correct data

Comment: Then show your attempts using a Tally or Calendar table on the question.

Comment: @ShivamVats that query doesn't use a calendar table. Have you actually tried using a calendar table?

Comment: I am just trying to remove recursive cte from first query, no i haven't

Comment: @ShivamVats what you posted is using `master..spt_values ` to generate numbers, not dates. `'12/1/1899'` is a localized string and could be January 12 or December 1. Even if the string was fixed the CTE doesn't generate a calendar table. It generates a list of *unindexed* month start days. The whole point of using a Calendar table is to get indexed field for all possible option and so avoid expensive table scans. And simplify querying. This query is anything but simple

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos please help me with the first one, i want the same output withous recursive cte

Comment: I just noticed, can the *from* date really be **after** the *to* date..?

Comment: @ShivamVats use a calendar table. A *real* table with the dates you want. Check that this table contains the correct dates. Right now, you have no idea what dates are there. *After* you do that, you can write a simple JOIN and check whether the results make sense. Are you trying to find rows that *overlap* a specific month? With a *proper* calendar table instead of a month list you wouldn't need that. You'd just group by the Month column

Comment: No i am just trying to seggregate date ranges into separate rows with all the columns

Comment: i need more than 100 months

Comment: I *assume* this is a reply to my answer, @ShivamVats . If so, then just add more `CROSS JOIN`s in the `Tally` CTE (I assumed 100  months would enough for a sample as that's a little over 8 years). Or, as mentioned multiple times, get a Calendar Table

Comment: @Larnu  I have updated above data, now could you please help. I am not getting the data either with calenderTable also

Comment: *"now could you please help"* I did.... I posted an answer 2 hours ago. If posting an answer isn't being "helpful" I don't know what is.

Comment: I am not saying that, you really helped me but i am not getting the data

Comment: The queries work for me, @ShivamVats . Here's the tally working: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f6b8d4d4c4bb148e0c4d963e9e88d064). I can't demonstrate a calendar table, as there isn't on of fiddle instance (but it works on my local environment, where I have a calendar table).

Answer (score 2):

This is a method using an inline tally:

```sql
DECLARE @d TABLE(value int ,from_date DATE, to_date DATE);
INSERT @d VALUES (7,'2013-11-25','2013-11-05'),(8,'2013-07-25','2013-12-05');

WITH N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT 0 AS I
    UNION ALL
    SELECT TOP (SELECT MAX(DATEDIFF(MONTH,from_date,to_date)) FROM @d)
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS I
    FROM N N1, N N2) --100 months, add more cross joins for more months
SELECT d.[value],
       CASE WHEN DATEADD(DAY,1,EOMONTH(DATEADD(MONTH,T.I,d.from_date),-1)) < d.from_date THEN d.from_date ELSE DATEADD(DAY,1,EOMONTH(DATEADD(MONTH,T.I,d.from_date),-1)) END AS mo_from_date,
       CASE WHEN EOMONTH(DATEADD(MONTH,T.I,d.from_date)) > d.to_date THEN d.to_date ELSE DATEADD(MONTH,T.I,d.from_date) END AS mo_to_date 
FROM @d d
     JOIN Tally T ON DATEDIFF(MONTH,from_date,to_date) >= T.I;
```

I do, personally, however, suggest you get yourself a Calendar Table, then the problem is far more simple:

```sql
SELECT d.[value],
       CASE WHEN d.from_date > MIN(CT.CalendarDate) THEN d.from_date ELSE MIN(CT.CalendarDate) END AS mo_from_date,
       CASE WHEN d.to_date < MAX(CT.CalendarDate) THEN d.to_date ELSE MAX(CT.CalendarDate) END AS mo_to_date
FROM @d d
     JOIN dbo.CalendarTable CT ON d.from_date <= CT.CalendarDate --To assumes that the to_date being before the
                              AND d.to_date >= CT.CalendarDate   --the from date is an error.
GROUP BY d.[value],
         d.from_date,
         d.to_date,
         MONTH(CT.CalendarDate),
         YEAR(CT.CalendarDate);
```

Both solutions assume that the *from* date should be *before* the *to* date though; even though that it appears to not be true in your data. If your *from* date can be *after* your *to* date, I would suggest you have data issues, as how can something **start** *after* it has **ended**?