# How to split a date range into separate years

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I have a Start_Date and End_Date. I want to split this in to several ranges.
Example:

| Emp_Name | Start_Dtm | End_Dtm |
| --- | --- | --- |
| xyz | 2020-09-16 | 2023-09-15 |
| ABC | 2020-06-10 | 2021-10-12 |

I want same in below format:

| Emp_Name | Start_Dtm | End_Dtm |
| --- | --- | --- |
| xyz | **2020-09-16** | 2020-12-31 |
| xyz | 2021-01-01 | 2021-12-31 |
| xyz | 2022-01-01 | 2022-12-31 |
| xyz | 2023-01-01 | **2023-09-15** |
| ABC | **2020-06-10** | 2020-12-31 |
| ABC | 2021-01-01 | **2021-10-12** |

Comment: I suggest investing in a Calendar table, then this is simple.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split date range into months (Using CTE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68525390/split-date-range-into-months-using-cte/68528266#68528266) The idea is *literally* the same, just you want years not months, which you should be able to implement easily if you take the time to understand it.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't have any calendar table, to generate number series from Start_Dtm and End_Dtm I have used `master..[spt_values]` table and use it with cross apply to created necessary new rows.
Then with common table expression and case when expression it's easy to do what you asked for.

DB-Fiddle:

```
 create table yourtable (Emp_Name varchar(50), Start_Dtm date, End_Dtm date);
 insert into yourtable values('xyz', '2020-09-16','2023-09-15');
 insert into yourtable values('ABC', '2020-06-10','2021-10-12');
```

Query:

```
 with cte as
 (
    select Emp_Name, Start_Dtm, End_Dtm, number,count(*)over(partition by Emp_Name, Start_Dtm, End_Dtm )cnt,
    DATEFROMPARTS(year(start_dtm)+number-1,1,1)New_Start_Dtm,
    DATEFROMPARTS(year(start_dtm)+number-1,12,31)New_End_Dtm 
    From yourtable 
    cross apply (select distinct number from master..[spt_values] 
    WHERE number BETWEEN 1 and 1+year(End_Dtm)-Year(Start_Dtm))as calendar (Number)
 )
 select Emp_Name, 
 (case when number=1 then Start_Dtm else New_Start_Dtm end)  Start_Dtm,
 (case when cnt>number then New_End_Dtm else End_Dtm end)  End_Dtm
 from cte
```

Output:

| Emp_Name | Start_Dtm | End_Dtm |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 2020-06-10 | 2020-12-31 |
| ABC | 2021-01-01 | 2021-10-12 |
| xyz | 2020-09-16 | 2020-12-31 |
| xyz | 2021-01-01 | 2021-12-31 |
| xyz | 2022-01-01 | 2022-12-31 |
| xyz | 2023-01-01 | 2023-09-15 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0dbf82336fe0f330ac5ed74da2f329cc)*

Answer (score 0):

This uses a table with years in it which is kind of hard coded. I would typically use a whole date dimension.

```
declare @y table (yr int)

insert into @y values(2018),(2019),(2020),(2021),(2022),(2023)

declare @d table (person varchar(100), startDte date, endDate date)

insert into @d values
('xyz', '2020-09-16',   '2023-09-15')
,('ABC',    '2020-06-10',   '2021-10-12')

select person
    ,startDte = iif(year(startDte)=ca.yr,startDte,Cast(cast(ca.yr as varchar(4)) + '0101' as date))
    ,endDate = iif(year(endDate) = ca.yr,endDate,cast(cast(ca.yr as varchar(4)) + '1231' as date))
from @d
    cross apply (select yr from @y where yr between year(startDte) and year(endDate)) ca
order by person,startDte
```

The cross apply will create a row for each year between start and enddates. And you use that year to determine what date to pick / create for the detail records.

Results:

```
person  startDte    endDate
ABC 2020-06-10  2020-12-31
ABC 2021-01-01  2021-10-12
xyz 2020-09-16  2020-12-31
xyz 2021-01-01  2021-12-31
xyz 2022-01-01  2022-12-31
xyz 2023-01-01  2023-09-15
```